# вместо записи md5 'recalculate' в таблице mysql

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс

Есть таблица с кодировкой utf8 и соединением utf8_unicode_ci одной базы. А
я запрашиваю данные из этой таблицы.

Беру колонку поставщик `suppliers` и записываю.

```
$code=md5($resAr['suppliers']);
$arElement['ID']=1;
$arElement['CODE']=$code;
```

Далее, вызываю функцию битрикса:

```
UpdateProd($arElement["ID"], 1, $arElement);
```

смотрю базу битрикса Б, таблицу `b_iblock_element` (таблица с кодировкой utf8 и соединением utf8_unicode_ci), в колонке `CODE` вместо md5 содержится `recalculate`.

Почему?

Comment: А что это за функция `UpdateProd`? Дело в том, что я не могу найти ее в официальной документации. Возможно, это самописная или недокументированная функция? Тогда хорошо бы ее тоже приложить к вопросу.